# In which package, can I find "AlsoNotifyChangeFor" in .Net MAUI?

Tags: maui

I'm using the package CommunityToolkit.Mvvm 8.0.0 in .Net MAUI.

I have a simple class as follows :

```
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Collections;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.DependencyInjection;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Messaging;

namespace My.ViewModels
{

    public partial class BaseViewModel:ObservableObject
    {
        public BaseViewModel()
        {
        }

        [ObservableProperty]
        [AlsoNotifyChangeFor(nameof(IsNotBusy))]   <<<< Compilation error here
        bool isBusy;

        [ObservableProperty]
        string title;

        public bool IsNotBusy => !isBusy;
    }
}
```

This class raises a compilation error on the attribute **AlsoNotifyChangeFor**.

It says "The type or namespace name could not be found" for this attribute to be used.

Where can I find the right package to use this attribute?

Comment: "Tell 'em James Montemagno sent ya! They'll know what to do." haha.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

in the [release notes](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/dotnet/releases/tag/v8.0.0-preview4), under **breaking changes**

```
[AlsoNotifyChangeFor] ---> [NotifyPropertyChangedFor]
```